# Developing MS Outlook Plugin using .NET

Tags: asp.net, outlook, outlook-addin

I am currently building 3-tired ASP.NET 3.5 Web application which has workflows built in for manager approvals. Currently there is a dashboard on the homepage of the website where all the   pending approvals are displayed in a webpart.  I want to build a plugin for MS Outlook so that whenever there is a new request for approval I want that request to show up in MS outlook. Where do I start with this? Do I have to expose my business logic layer through webservices? Can anyone please point me towards some useful material or books?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) code in the past, but I think you should check out [this video on the Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb738107.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, but I can give you a quick heads up.

Have built a single add-on to Outlook 2007.  between 2003 and 2007 you develop the add-ons differently. Since the introduction of the Ribbon 2007.

I used WCF to setup Web Services (a simple API) within my web application. Then, connected to that API from an Outlook application.  If I remember correctly, there is a template in visual studio to use for building Office Add-ins.

I just did some google searching and this was nearly 2 years ago.  there was very limited info then. Now there should be more.

Hope that helps.